# Pointer compatibility from VS2015 to VS2008

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2008

In a header file that I cannot modify, I have:

```
void SetReceiveCallback(void (*funcRXReceiveDataptr)(char* data, int length));
```

In my cpp code, I have:

```
void pcsocketcommunication::receiveData(char* data, int length)
{
}
    communication = new CommunicationInterface(true, "192.168.214.1", 41682, 2000000, 41681, 2000000);
    communication->SetReceiveCallback((void *)(&pcsocketcommunication::receiveData));
```

I can compile with VS2015 but VS2008 says:

`error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall pcsocketcommunication::* )(char *,int)' to 'void *'`

How can I modify the calling function to be able to compile in VS2008 ?

Comment: You need to provide a pointer to function with required signature. Note that no cast should be used here and that function can not be a non-static member function.

Comment: If it compiled in VS2008, it is because VS2008 was flawed, and the flaw has been fixed in VS2015.  A pointer to member, in all versions of standard C++, is not convertible to a `void *`. To get the code to *compile*, simply change `receiveData()` so it is a `static` member of class `pcscocketcommunication`. Nobody can guess if the code will then run correctly - since you have provided no information relevant to that.   I suspect you will find that `pcsocketcommunication::receiveData` is never actually called - i.e. it was more luck than good planning that the code worked with VS2008 at all.

Comment: @Peter The OP described it vice versa. It compiles in VS2015 but not in VS2008: _I can compile with VS2015 but VS2008 says: ..._ To justice whether the call is correct, you have to know how `pcsocketcommunication::receiveData()` is declared. A `static` member function would be acceptable. It's the `to void*` in the error message which makes me very uncertain...

Comment: @Scheff - That's even worse then.   It means that VS2015 has introduced a flaw.   The error message indicates an attempt to convert a pointer to a non-static member to `void *` - which is not valid in any version of C++.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but concerning the title _Pointer compatibility from VS2015 to VS2008_: You cannot mix C++ code from VS2008 and VS2015 (e.g. by using a VS2008 compiled DLL in a VS2015 compiled EXE or DLL). AFAIK, it's not binary compatible. Either you have to compile all with VS2008 or all with VS2015.

Comment: @Peter Though, the exposed signature of `SetReceiveCallback()` doesn't show any (wrong) `void*`...

Comment: @Scheff - The error message "cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall pcsocketcommunication::* )(char *,int)' to 'void *'" indicates the compiler thinks the function is a non-static member function.

Comment: @Peter That might be the case. I looked into [C2440](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=msvc-160) but it didn't help much. It seems that the error code is used for any type incompatibility. The OP should provide more info...

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: A minimal reproducible example can be found here:
https://chrigou.net/pctest.zip

Comment: a [mre] would look like this:https://godbolt.org/z/13j3a4 and needs to be edited into the question itself not as a comment.